# Регулярное выражение для поиска полных ссылок с файлами

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Использую `(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[\w\.]+)\.(?:[a-z]{2,6}\.?)(?:\/[\w\.]*)*\/?` для поиска ссылок на сайте. Но мне оно не подходит так как ссылка должна быть в виде ссылки на файл или картинку. Не как не могу найти регулярное выражение для поиска ссылок с файлами пример: `<brbrbr> okk http://fooo-bar.com/more/than/file.exe`. Должно найти `http://fooo-bar.com/more/than/file.exe`. Подскажите пожалуйста `Regexp` для этого.

Comment: Я всегда [**вот это**](https://regex101.com/r/7J1Yq4/1) использую для поиска ссылок. Оно работает при условии, что в URL нет разрывного пробела. Спасибо.

Comment: на произвольный файл или какой?

Comment: Концептуальный вопрос: чем отличается "ссылка с файлами" от любых других URI?

Comment: Не знаю. Я не могу по другому объяснить.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    let input = "<a href='http://fooo-bar.com/more/than/file.exe'><h1><b>HackerRank</b></h1></a>";
    // находим все теги а
    let arr = input.match(/<a\s.+?>.*?<\/a>/g);        
    // извлекаем атрибут href c текстом
    arr = input.match(/(href=['"])(.+?)['"]/g);

    for(let str of arr) {
        str = str.replace(/(^href=['"]|['"]$)/g, ''); // удаляем символы до и после HTML адреса
        console.log(str);
    }
</script>
```

Советую пройти курс по регулярным выражениям на сайте Hackerrank
https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/regex/re-introduction

Кстати там есть задача такая же, как и у вас
Detect HTML links

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/detect-html-links/problem

Comment: Ваше регулярное выражение должно находит в начале http в конце .exe|.gif|.jpg. На курсах такому учат?

Answer (score 1):

**НЕ ВЕРНО**

```
http[s]?:\/(?:\/[^\/]+){1,}(?:\/[А-Яа-я\w ]+\.[a-z]{3,5}(?![\/]))
```

Должно искать только ссылки где в конце точка и три-пять буквенных символов.
Пример работы: https://regex101.com/r/cv8STi/1

---

**Вероятнее верно**
UPD: нашел проблему, что выбирались строки где более 5 символов после точки, игнорируя остальные.

```
http[s]?:\/(?:\/[^\/]+){1,}(?:\/[А-Яа-яёЁ\w ]+\.[a-z]{3,5}(?![\/]|[\wА-Яа-яёЁ]))
```

https://regex101.com/r/cv8STi/4

Более подробно о шаблоне:

`http[s]?` - http или https, т.е. символ s считается необязательным
`:\/` - статичные символы :/ с экраном
`(?:\/[^\/]+){1,}` - не захватываемая группа выбора всех символов между двумя / с квантификатором 1 и более раз
`(?:\/[А-Яа-яёЁ\w ]+\.[a-z]{3,5}` - не захватываемая группа букв и цифр от 1 и более символов совпадения, в конце обязательное наличие символ точки и от 3 до 5 латинских цифр
`(?![\/]|[\wА-Яа-яёЁ]))` - проверка что за пределами не остался символ / любой символ букв или цифр, т.е. .../a.aaaa является концом строки или отделено синтаксически.